Script to join domain works for me but not coworkers
So I'm using a script to join a PC to the domain. It's run via a batch file in the startup folder. It opens properly for them and asks them for credentials. After they enter their credentials, nothing happens. The PC remains in the work group instead of joining the domain. It works for me, but not my coworkers (they have admin credentials just like I do). Any idea why?

$WSID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your desired workstation ID'


Add-Computer -ComputerName $WSID -DomainName Redacted


Remove-Item -Path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp#4_Join_Domain.bat' -Force
Remove-Item $PSCommandPath -Force


Domain join hardening:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5020276-netjoin-domain-join-hardening-changes-2b65a0f3-1f4c-42ef-ac0f-1caaf421baf8

"they have admin credentials just like I do", you need to have local admin rights and domain admin rights to be able to join a machine to the domain...

We all sign into a local admin account (its added to each PC as part of our image), the the batch file opens (because its in the startup folder) then we enter our credentials when it asks us to. Works for me, but not them.

See domain join hardening.  These days only the creator of a computer object can join it, unless other steps are taken.
